# Gimp interface text orientation

Tags: gimp

I an using an en-US windows and my locale is he (rtl text).
I downloaded an English Gimp installer and got the program interface as rtl
(see the menu example)

[image]

also the windows (rtl directions)

[image]

How do I change all program interface to ltr ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the environment variable:

LC_ALL=en

That should do the trick. To set an environment variable you can follow these steps:

http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html